# Line wrapping breaks when using 'cw' in vim

Tags: vim, line-breaks

I write my LaTeX files with line breaks after paragraphs, and with soft wrapping (i.e., my .vimrc has `set wrap linebreak` for *.tex files).

The line wrapping generally works great, but when I use `cw` to start editing a paragraph it breaks. The text still wraps, but it wraps at the end of the line, instead of wrapping between words.

What is different about entering insert mode via `cw` instead of `i` that would cause that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens with linebreaks when you do `dw`, same?

Comment: First steps are to check out your `.vimrc` file(s) and/or your vim version and the options with which it was compiled; to check the latter, execute `:version` within `vim`.

Comment: dw works fine, and breaks as expected.

I'm realizing now that my question isn't clear - the line is breaking, but it isn't breaking at wordbreaks. That is - the set wrap is working but set linebreak isn't. I'll edit the question to clarify.